# Why does this Angular ui router code cause an infinite loop in $digest?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've boiled the code down as much as I can.  Something about nested states and the event handling/broadcasting is causing an infinite loop.  In Chrome I can pause it and see that it is looping forever in Angular's `$digest` function. Any idea why?  Is it a bug in my example code, or a bug in [Angular](http://angularjs.org), or the [UI Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)?

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app='bugapp' ng-controller='BugAppCtrl'>
<head>
  <script src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js'></script>

  <!-- Angular 1.2.11 -->
  <script src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.js'></script>

  <!-- UI router 0.2.8 -->
  <script src='//cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.js'></script>

  <script>
angular.module('bugapp', ['ui.router'])
  .run(function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
  })
  .config(function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    $stateProvider
      .state("root", {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/servletContext?asUser",
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'  // ???
      })
      .state("root.home", {
        abstract: true,
        url: "/home",
        template: "<div ng-if='hasData()' ui-view ></div>"

      })
      .state("root.home.profile", {
        url: "/profile",
        template: '<div>whatever</div>'
      })

  })
  .controller('BugAppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $log, $location) {
    $log.log('BugAppCtrl: constructor');

    $scope.hasData = function() {
      var res = !!$scope.foo;
      // $log.log("hasData called, returing " + res + " foo is " + $scope.foo);
      return res;
    };

    $scope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function () {
      $log.log("State changed! (to " + $state.current.name + ")");
      $scope.foo = 'junk';
      $scope.$broadcast("resetfoo");
    });

    $state.go('root.home.profile');
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect this is a bug in the UI Router, for two reasons:

1. I tried your code and then tried downgrading the version of UI
   Router to 0.2.7. When I used 0.2.7, it worked.
2. Even if you keep using version 0.2.8 of UI Router, if you perform the state change through $location instead of $state, it works. Here's an example of using $location instead of the $state.go call:

   ```
   $location.path('/servletContext/home/profile');
   ```

Although I use and recommend UI Router (can't do without nested views), if you find in the future that you want to do any sort of intercepting or redirecting when the user tries to go to certain pages, I recommend using $location.path instead of $state, for reasons I described [in a blog post](http://mattmetlis.blogspot.com/2013/12/angularui-router-state-and-location.html)

**Edit**: I haven't tried with parameters before but just tried with the code you posted (I created a 2nd controller and assigned it to your 'root.home.profile' state), and it works. Instructions from UI Router are [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#wiki-url-parameters). But basically if you set your URL in your state definition the same way you would with UI Router:

```
url: "/profile/:foo",
```

then in your $location.path call add the parameter in the path:

```
$location.path('/servletContext/home/profile/12');
```

and you can access the 12 in the controller from

```
$stateParams.foo
```

Comment: That's very helpful. When you use $location instead of $state, have you successfully transitioned to a state with parameters in that way?

Comment: Looks like it's possible - I tried it and added info in my answer.

Comment: For me it's the same with location path, I am emitting some events

Comment: Seems slightly preferable to at least let UI Router construct the location you will be changing to, aka:

`$location.path( $state.href('my.state.name', {foo: 'bar'});`