# Infinite Loop on ui-router's $stateChangeStart

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ramping up on **angular**, and **ui-router**

And struggling with redirecting to a different state if a precondition is not met:

I tried using an interceptor: ([How do I preform a redirect in an angular interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992724/how-do-i-preform-a-redirect-in-an-angular-interceptor)).

But someone mentioned that handling $stateChangeState would be more appropriate.  But I am still running into an infinite loop:

```
    /**
     *  Check here for preconditions of state transitions
     */
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

        // which states in accounts to be selected
        var accountRequiredStates = ['user.list', 'user.new'];
        if(_.contains(accountRequiredStates, toState.name)){
            event.preventDefault();
            ApiAccount.customGET('get_current').then(function(resp){
                // if I have a selected account, go about your business
                if(resp.hasOwnProperty('id')){
                    $state.go(toState.name);
                } else { // prompt user to select account
                    $state.go('user.select_account');
                }
            })
        }
    });
```

Can anyone suggest a better pattern (one that works)

Thanks!

---

Note: Similar problem different approach here: [How do I preform a redirect in an angular interceptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992724/how-do-i-preform-a-redirect-in-an-angular-interceptor)

Comment: you should only prevent the event if you want to redirect. I guess `$state.go` has to be wrapped into a `$timeout` function.

Comment: thanks -- could you share a code snipit?

Comment: I think your question is duplciate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631896/why-does-this-angular-ui-router-code-cause-an-infinite-loop-in-digest

Comment: Jonathan,

did you resolve this?  If so, can you post your solution?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything wrong with the general way you're trying to do this, though I'm not an expert. I do see a flaw in the implementation which looks like it could cause an infinite loop. Let's say the user tries to go to 'user.new' state. Your $stateChangeStart listener intercepts that, cancels it, does your customGET; then if the inner if condition is true (`resp.hasOwnProperty('id')`), you try to send the user to the same 'user.new' state. At which point, your $stateChangeStart listener intercepts it, cancels it, etc., over and over.

The way I avoid this problem in my code is to have a variable (in the service where I declare the listener) to help me bypass that check:
`var middleOfRedirecting = false;` Inside your inner if block within the `resp.hasOwnProperty('id')` check, set middleOfRedirecting to true; add a condition at the start of your $stateChangeStart listener to only call `event.preventDefault()` and redirect if middleOfRedirecting is false. You also would need a $stateChangeSuccess listener to set middleOfRedirecting back to false, resetting it for the next state change. (I feel like there should be a better way than this, but it at least works.)